# CSS button error?

Tags: html, css

I have my css button that wont work, it only comes up as a simple hyper link..
I have it all setup right with the css reference and everything.. Heres a look at my code:

```css
.B1 {
 background-color:#44c767;
 -moz-border-radius:16px;
 -webkit-border-radius:16px;
 border-radius:16px;
 border:4px solid #18ab29;
 display:inline-block;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#ffffff;
 font-family:arial;
 font-size:17px;
 padding:18px 63px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-shadow:1px 0px 8px #2f6627;
}
.B1:hover {
 background-color:#5cbf2a;
}
.B1:active {
 position:relative;
 top:1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Tutorial</title>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///Users/lucasaltmann/Desktop/styles2.css">
</head>
<body bgcolor="Green">
<center>
<h1 style="color:orange">Welcome to CocoaCraft!</h1>
<a class="B1" href="http://cocoacraftnetwork.buycraft.net">Donate</a>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS is top and HTML is bottom. It runs fine when I run it on here but its not working for me..

PS: I am running mac snow leopard and firefox (Chrome did not work either)

Comment: What about is isn't working? It looks to be working to me when I run the code snippet.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code. This might be a shot in the dark, but try setting your classname in lowercase characters. It might be a case sensitiveness issue.

Comment: it works here for me here. i'm using safari.

Comment: @andufo, that's not the problem.  He said his code is working fine in this code snippet, but not on his site.  Sorry, Lucas, but it seems that your problem is not replicatable.

Comment: Can you link us to the page on your site where this is hosted? Chances are there is something else you're loading on your site that might be conflicting with the button

Comment: @DavidLerner its not a site its just a regular .html file

Comment: Then upload the .html file to your host and watch it suddenly, magically become a site. What is inside of styles2.css? Did you paste the entirety of that document here?

Comment: @DavidLerner I don't know how to do any of that. I am only 14 years of age, and I'm trying to learn basic html/css, my brother told me too he his a billionaire of making websites.

Comment: @DavidLerner Just uploading it won't work, because the css file is referenced using `file` scheme.

Comment: @Oriol Correct. I overlooked that point. I think, in the author's case, the answer has already been given. Just include the styles within the document and call it a day. He'll figure out how to link external resources when he turns 15, maybe, or his brother Mark Z. decides to show him.

Comment: Thank you everyone for trying to help me. My brother was just here for dinner but showed me on a windows, Ill get him to show me another time! Thanks @DavidLerner for everything and everyone else.

Comment: @Lucas Ask your brother to teach me to be a billionaire at making websites, too, please.

Comment: @DavidLerner hes a millionaire. But its not just making websites, he has an engineering company in which makes most of his money.

Comment: Oh, psh. Everyone's a millionaire in our hyperinflated economy. Not interested. Good luck with learning to load stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

It works here but not on your computer - well the CSS is probably not loaded correctly. You have an absolute path to the CSS file, so try this instad:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Tutorial</title>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles2.css">
</head>
<body bgcolor="Green">
<center>
<h1 style="color:orange">Welcome to CocoaCraft!</h1>
<a class="B1" href="http://cocoacraftnetwork.buycraft.net">Donate</a>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Put you .html and style2.css in the same folder and it should work.

**Another solution:**

Replace your html with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Tutorial</title>
<head>
<style>
.B1 {
    background-color:#44c767;
    -moz-border-radius:16px;
    -webkit-border-radius:16px;
    border-radius:16px;
    border:4px solid #18ab29;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:17px;
    padding:18px 63px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 0px 8px #2f6627;
}
.B1:hover {
    background-color:#5cbf2a;
}
.B1:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="Green">
<center>
<h1 style="color:orange">Welcome to CocoaCraft!</h1>
<a class="B1" href="http://cocoacraftnetwork.buycraft.net">Donate</a>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the CSS is inside the html file.

Comment: While technically correct, these methods are outside of best practices and just lead to messy files/directories.

Comment: In *some* cases, you are correct, @DavidLerner.  This is possibly a good solution for the OP.